# PHP Working Directory for Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Following this [Google Calendar API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) I downloaded the `credentials.json` file and moved it to `D:\googlecalendar\credentials.json` as I presume that `D:\googlecalendar` is the working directory. I kept getting this error and kept moving the file to each deeper directory one at a time and rerunning the file from the command line until it was located in `D:\googlecalendar\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\`.

Where is the "working directory"? ︎

> D:>php D:\googlecalendar\quickstart.php
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> InvalidArgumentException: file does not exist: credentials.json in
> D:\googlecalendar\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php:839
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 D:\googlecalendar\quickstart.php(17): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('credentials.jso...')
>
> 1 D:\googlecalendar\quickstart.php(52): getClient()
>
> 2 {main}   thrown in D:\googlecalendar\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on
> line 839

Answer (score 0):

Apparently even though the project is located at D:\googlecalendar\ the "working directory" is D:\. ︎